# Tensorflow, where (index) 'and' conditional

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following Tensor:

```
# (class, index)
obj_class_indexes = tf.constant([(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3)])
```

And to each value I'm looking for the objects with the same class.
For now I'm trying the following:

```
same_classes = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(obj_classes_indexes[:, 0], obj_classes_indexes[0][0]), \
                                        obj_classes_indexes[:, 1]  > obj_classes_indexes[0][1])
found_indexes = tf.where(same_classes)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(same_classes))
    print(sess.run(indexes))
```

The expected output would be:

```
[False  True  True False]
[1, 2]
```

But it's giving me:

```
[False  True  True False]
[[1], [2]]
```

I don't think the `logical_and` output is actually the correct input to the `tf.where` function. Or Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothin wrong with the output. tf.where() is expected to output a 2D tensor as quoted [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where):
"The coordinates are returned in a 2-D tensor where the first dimension (rows) represents the number of true elements, and the second dimension (columns) represents the coordinates of the true elements"

If you want the output to be a 1D tensor as you have mentioned, you could just add a reshape op in your case as below:

```
found_indexes = tf.where(same_classes)
found_indexes = tf.reshape(found_indexes, [-1])
```

hope this helps!

Comment: This is correct, just as an alternative, one could write `found_indexes = tf.where(same_classes)[:, 0]`, which is to take the first (and only) "column" in the 2D tensor.

Comment: I exchanged the next gather function, to a gather_nd, so having this different output did not changed the expected output of the gather_nd.
It worked, so thanks for the clarifying answer!